# Using CASE for multiple conditions in MySQL query

Tags: mysql

Here's a MySQL  query which I am using to get the roles for a user along with the comments. 
But there are some cases where a user can be admin for multiple cases, in which case this query doesn't work.

This only shows up the first role of the user as an admin.

What would be the right way to use `case` for this situation?

```
   select u.fullname, c.comment,
     case when u.n_admin = 1 then 'n_admin'
          when u.c_admin = 1 then 'c_admin'
          when u.t_admin = 1 then 't_admin'
          when u.i_admin = 1 then 'i admin'
          end as role
     from  comments c
     left join users u on u.id = c.user_id 
     where c.id= 34
```

Comment: I wouldn't use a `case` statement in this instance. If your users can have multiple roles, then you need to be able to see that. here, you are wrapping all their roles into one, and you are losing information.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated by @Matt-Spinks, your query is wrapping all the roles into one column.

Since, based on your query, `user` can have multiple independent admin roles (`u.n_admin, u.c_admin etc`), then you should report each column separately.

Since each only can be true or false, I would do it with `IF()` instead of `CASE()`:

```
SELECT u.fullname, c.comment,
     IF(u.n_admin = 1,'Yes','No') AS 'has n_admin role',
     IF(u.c_admin = 1,'Yes','No') AS 'has c_admin role',
     IF(u.t_admin = 1,'Yes','No') AS 'has t_admin role',
     IF(u.i_admin = 1,'Yes','No') AS 'has i_admin role'
     FROM  comments c
     LEFT JOIN users u on u.id = c.user_id 
     WHERE c.id= 34
```